# Reverse a words in string without change in order and also number of blank spaces in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, reverse

I want to reverse all the words in a string such that

1. Orders of the words should not be change
2. Number of blank spaces in the words should be remain the same

```
For Ex:- When my string is "How     Are  You" it should return "woH     erA  uoY"
```

I tries something like following

```
def reverse_string(str)
  arr = str.split(" ")
  new_arr = arr.collect{|a| a.reverse}
  new_arr.join(" ")
end
```

But it will not work for the strings which may have multiple blank spaces between the words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = "How     Are  You"
s.gsub(/\w+/) { |match| match.reverse }
```

Comment: but when we'll join the array, how they came to know the spaces between 'woH' and 'erA' should be same as spaces between 'How' and 'Are' i.e. 4 AND and spaces between 'erA' and 'uoY' should be same as 'Are' and 'You' i.e. 2

Comment: @Salil Have you tried to run this code? It works as in the example you gave in the question

Answer (score 3):

This one is the shortest possible and probably the fastest too.
The string is regex'ed and all  successive word characters are reversed in order

```
s = "How     Are  You"
s.gsub(/\w+/,&:reverse) 

=>woH     erA  uoY
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. Using a regex for spliting in  *Any word boundary character*

```
def reverse_string str
  arr = str.split /\b/
  new_arr = arr.collect {|a| a.reverse}
  new_arr.join
end
```

Comment: but when we'll join the array, how they came to know the spaces between 'woH' and 'erA' should be same as spaces between 'How' and 'Are' i.e. 4 AND and spaces between 'erA' and 'uoY' should be same as 'Are' and 'You' i.e. 2